# how can i use correctly the functions which have been already developed in javascript into an application in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, import

i am developping an application web in angular 4.Otherwise, there were also another application that has been developed in javascript, i got to use the D3JS functions that have been already created in app Javascript for my app in ang4. I have already imported and called these functions but i got an error when i tested : **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined** . Indeed, min is the function of variable d3 which is 
an instance of class D3JS , so d3 can use the methode like scaleLinear, axisLeft ...
So here are the images :

[in function test hello,it calls the function draw_cpuLoadMonitorChart that has been exported from the JavaScript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7kbt.png)

[the function draw_cpuLoadMonitorChart and d3 that i exported to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieQkW.png)

[the error that i got when i cliked the button Try It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcnvD.png)

[file html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuK8k.png)

Comment: Screenshots are near useless. You need to write a working snippet. http://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this particular package, but what you are looking for are typings for D3.js:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/d3

Add this type definitions to your project, and you should be good to go.

https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#installable-typings-files